# Is the .flac audio file format supported by Wordpress?

Tags: audio

It works for me but I can't find evidence of it being officially supported so I'm concerned it may not work for everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the flac audio format is supported. See the [doc block for the function `wp_get_mime_types()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c38bdce55be070403519539c1791e3d9d4708dcd/wp-includes/functions.php#L3071) (and [other mentions](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?q=flac)).

```
/**
 * Retrieve list of mime types and file extensions.
 *
 * @since 3.5.0
 * @since 4.2.0 Support was added for GIMP (.xcf) files.
 * @since 4.9.2 Support was added for Flac (.flac) files.
 * @since 4.9.6 Support was added for AAC (.aac) files.
 *
 * @return string[] Array of mime types keyed by the file extension regex corresponding to those types.
 */
function wp_get_mime_types() {
```

Whether the visitor's browser supports it is a completely different question and not in WordPress' hands.